# Merging dfs when values of columns are str that are identical at specific locations of the str's slice

Tags: python, pandas, compare

let's say I have two dfs as follows:

```
data1= {'Column': ['01A01', '03C12', '04F23']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Plate': ['1A1', '3D14', '1B6']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I would like to find the values (str) from df1 that their second and third letter match the first and second letter of df2. When they match, extract the full row from each df and merge them.
Accordingly, in this example, '01A01' and '1A1' should match.

My approach was something like:

```
def letter_matcher(df1, df2, left_key=str, right_key=str): 

    full_list1 = []  
    full_list2 = []
    
    for value1 in df1[left_key]:
        list1 = [value1[1], value1[2]]
        full_list1.append(list1)
        df1['new1'] = full_list2
   
    for value2 in df2[right_key]:
        list2 = [value2[0], value2[1]]
        full_list2.append(list2)
        df2['new2'] = full_list2
        
    df_new = df1.merge(df2, left_on=new1, right_on=new2 , how='inner')
  
    if df_new:
            
            print(df_new.head())
    else:
            print('No result')
```

Your help for revising the code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common `key` between dataframes to identify rows and merge them:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1.assign(key=df1['Column'].str[1:3]),
             df2.assign(key=df2['Plate'].str[0:2]),
             how='left').drop(columns='key')

  Column Plate
0  01A01   1A1
1  03C12   NaN
2  04F23   NaN
```

Refer to the documentation of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to adjust the parameter `how`. Here I choose `left` to keep rows from `df1`.

**Update**

> I need to match several inconsistent letters: df1--> str[1:3] and str [9:], df2--> str[0:2] and str[6:7] , or even a longer str, how the script will look like?

Use `apply` instead of `str[]`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2,
         left_on=df1['Column'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([x[1:3], x[9:]])),
         right_on=df2['Plate'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([x[0:2], x[6:7]])))
```

Comment: Thank a lot! And as I need to add more conditions to it, I am wondering how to add more str[] to it. For example if df1 instead has '01A010004' and df2 has '1A100400', and I need to match several inconsistent letters: df1--> str[1:3] and str [9:], df2--> str[0:2] and str[6:7] , or even a longer str, how the script will look like?

Comment: @Ardalan1. I updated my answer. Does it answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Just merge on the sliced strings.

Code below

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=df1['Column'].str[1:3], right_on=df2['Plate'].str[0:2])
```

Comment: thank a lot! And as I need to add more conditions to it, I am wondering how to add more str[] to it. For example if df1 instead has '01A010004' and df2 has '1A100400', and I need to match several inconsistent letters: df1--> str[1:3] and str [9:], df2--> str[0:2] and str[6:7] , or even a longer str, how the script will look like?